# How to call a function in PHP in another form?

Tags: php, function

I have a page with name `1.php` that has a function in it. Now I want to call the function in `2.php` in PHP 2. I wrote `func();` this function is in `1.php`.

But it has this error:

```
Fatal error: Call to undefined function func() in C:\xampp\htdocs\me\2.php on line 2
```

How can I do that?

Comment: include() or require() 1.php in 2.php

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Include the script that contains the function you need using the `require_once()` method, like this:

```
require_once("../path/to/script.php");
```

Once you use the above method, PHP basically tacks the included script into the parent script, which will allow you to call functions, methods, and variables, as if they were in the parent script itself.

I would recommend `require_once()` over `include()`, `include_once()`, or `require()`, because this method will make sure that the script you are looking for exists, and is only called once. Calling the same script more than once (usually happening by accident) can cause strange problems in your script.

I hope that helps.

Comment: i wrote this in 2.php **require_once('Untitled 2.php');** but it has this error:**Fatal error: Call to undefined function mehdi() in C:\xampp\htdocs\me\Untitled 3.php on line 3**

Comment: I would guess one of two things, either your path the PHP script is incorrect, or the function isn't defined in the script you are including.