# Submit a form and then insert values in a php function

Tags: php, function

I have a form where i want to submit two entries. Its the entry_id and email. I have a php function that begins something like this:

```
    public function theFunction($data) {
    if (false && !empty($data['email']) && !empty($data['entry_id']) ) {
        $sql = $this->db->select()
            ->from('votes')
            ->where('entry_id = ?', $data['entry_id'])
            ->where('email = ?', $data['email'])
            ->order('created DESC');
```

But how am i supposed to call this function from a php file and bringing the values from the form with me, this is far as i've come but it doesent seem to work:

```
$fields = array("email","entry_id");
$data = array();
foreach($fields as $field){
    $data[$field] = $_POST[$field];
}

echo theFunction($data);
```

Does anyone know how i should do?

Comment: I don't really understand the question, but it sounds like you want include filename.php. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5942224/how-to-call-a-function-in-php-in-another-form

Comment: You may want to check that function again.  The conditional `if(false && ...)` will always return `false` and the sql will never be executed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This looks fine aside from this:

```
if (false && !empty($data['email']) && !empty($data['entry_id']) ) {
```

This will never be true because of the false.

Comment: @Paparappa No problem. No reason to feel stupid, happens to us all :)

Answer (score 1):

(CodeIgniter? Just curious, it has a big impact on a question like this.)

Change this:

```
if (false && !empty($data['email']) && !empty($data['entry_id']) ) {
```

to this:

```
if (!empty($data['email']) && !empty($data['entry_id'])) {
```

Never start a logical && comparison with false, PHP exits on the **first** false answer it finds and does not execute any additional tests. Your code is cut off, is that the whole function body? Does it return anything? What happens to $sql? If your function doesn't return anything, echo has nothing to output so you wouldn't see anything either way. >_> Example, placing

```
} else { return $result = 'test failed'; }
```

after the if to catch failures would have alerted you to the comparison problem.

Last thing, maybe try changing this:

```
echo theFunction($data);
```

to this:

```
$test = theFunction($data);
var_dump($test);
```

var_dump() leaves no room for doubt. Good luck, hth ;)