# Function defined in included file breaking wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, include

Here is my code:

single-location.php

```
            <?php
            // include start_dates.php
            include('start_dates.php'); // contians the start dates and a helper function contains()
            $crazy = crazyness_rad(); // breaks the page for some reason
```

start_dates.php

```
<?php
// simple test function that returns a string...
function crazyness_rad() {
    return 'WLHLHDFLDHFLDHF KJDHF KJDHF KLJDHF K';
}
```

And when I call this function from single-location.php it breaks the page...this works outside of wordpress just fine.

Why if I call a function defined in an include does it break? Thanks for the help with my noob question.

The error I get is:

*Fatal error: Call to undefined function crazyness_rad() in C:\inetpub\larockwww\wp-content\themes\larock-academy\single-location.php on line 51*

I just moved the function from the start_dates.php into the single-location.php and it works fine:

single-location.php

```
            <?php
            // include start_dates.php
            include('start_dates.php'); // contains the start dates and a 


            // Moved into this file
            function crazyness_rad() {
                return 'WLHLHDFLDHFLDHF KJDHF KJDHF KLJDHF K';
            }

            $crazy = crazyness_rad(); // works fine IT seems the include isn't working..
```

Comment: Define 'breaks the page'? Are you returned any error? What does the page look like? Also, have you tried without the function (ie, checked if its the `include()` and not the function itself that's breaking the page)?

Comment: @PeregrineStudios The page quites loading from that point. So I get the header an H1 then this function is called here...then nothing below that is loaded. I could enable debugging in the wp-config..stay tuned for message.

Comment: @PeregrineStudios I get an undefined function error...

Comment: Try changing `include()` to `require()` to check if your include is working. It sounds like it isn't. Is the include path correct?

Comment: @PeregrineStudios I changed it to require and same thing. The start_dates.php file is at the same leve the single-location.php is on the server (in the theme directory). Question: Is include a relative path? I believe it is but I could be wrong. Also wouldn't php throw an error if the file was not found? It works outside of wordpress - so include('pathtofile.php') is relative.

Comment: This has worked for me in the past doing a similar thing: `<?php include(locate_template('start_dates.php')); ?>`

Comment: `include` *is* a relative path, but when you're working with frameworks or CMS's like WordPress that operate off `index.php` in the webroot, path inclusion is always interesting. I'll be honest, I'm not 100% sure what the proper way to include a path is in WordPress, but I'd start there.

Comment: @NateBeers That didnt work. Thanks though.

Comment: Another question here is similar and says to use `require_once()` http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11192907/calling-a-function-in-a-custom-php-template-in-wordpress

Comment: @NateBeers That worked!! I also re-uploaded the start_dates.php as well...

Comment: @Radmation Awesome!

Answer (score 1):

seems that file `start_dates.php` is not in the correct path. Please include with the absolute path of the file . You can also try `get_template_part` function to include the file.
https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_template_part/

Comment: Please check the file permissions which you are including .